# automatic importing of data from csv to a mysql table with validation

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have 2 tables :

### product_category_master

id | product_category_name

### product_master

id | product_category_id | product_name

Format of data in csv file is as follows:

### xyz_product_details.csv

id | product_category_name | product_name

I am trying to write a  script that will automatically read a csv file from a 'Data' folder in the webserver every time a new csv file is uploaded and it will read the data from the above format csv file and validate data against product_category_name from the product_category_master table, fetch the product_category_id, then check if the product_category_id and product_name exists in a row in in the product_master table and if it does not exists then, it should insert the record in the product_master table. This should be done for all records in the csv file. Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: Welcome! To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you.**

Answer (score -1):

Here is the basic code, I haven't tested it though. make the product id or name unique to avoid duplicates in the database table. Yeah. but code requests are not done!! here!!!

```
 $handle =  fopen('data/yourcsvfilename.csv', 'r');
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','databasename');
    while($data = fgetcsv($handle)){
$id = $data[0];
$category = $data[1];
$product = $data[2];

$qgetcatid = "select id from product_category_master where category = '{$category}'";
$rgetcatid = mysqli_query($conn, $qgetcatid) or die (mysqli_error($conn));  

$rgetcatid = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rgetcatid);

$catid = $rgetcatid[0];

$qi = "insert ignore into product_master set product_name = '{$product}', id = '{$id}', product_cat_id = '{$catid}'"; 
$rgetcatid = mysqli_query($conn, $qi) or die (mysqli_error($conn)); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs. Will definitely try it out